# Handle database table with null dates using Nullable(Of Date)

Tags: vb.net, properties, nullable, dbnull

I have a SQL Server table with several date columns that can be `NULL` and in fact are `NULL`.

I thought I was handling this correctly by using the **.HasValue** test before trying for the value of a nullable type. But apparently not because I'm getting an *InvalidOperationException* - **Nullable object must have a value** - when the getter in my class object tries to populate a textbox:

```
Public Class EventItem
    Private _AcknowledgeDate As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property AcknowledgeDate() As Date?
        Get
            Return _AcknowledgeDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date?)
            If value.HasValue Then
                _AcknowledgeDate = value
            Else
                _AcknowledgeDate = Nothing
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

my constructor gets data from SQL server; here is the fragment from constructor:

```
Me.AcknowledgeDate = If(IsDBNull(theRdr("AcknowledgeDate")), Nothing, theRdr("AcknowledgeDate"))
```

When the above setter runs the date is Null and the private variable **_AcknowledgeDate** is set to **Nothing**.

When the code tries to assign something to the textbox, the getter code gets the exception here:

```
txtAcknowledgeDate.Text = thisEvent.AcknowledgeDate
```

I can make assign the textbox as follows:  txtAcknowledgeDate.Text = Nothing

Despite reading quite a bit about this nullable type facility, I guess I am quite confused about how to implement nullable dates in VB.Net.

Comment: what would you like to read in your Textbox in case of a `NULL` date? empty string?

Comment: I was thinking that a null date from the database could be stored as Nothing in the VB.Net object and I thought assigning Nothing to the .Text property of a textbox would be OK.

Comment: I modified my answer to provide more info. A NULL date can be stored as Nothing, the problem lies in its use for the Textbox field. just use an empty string instead of nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AcknowledgeDate` is already `Nothing`, you're setting it yourself in the constructor. You don't need to specify that again in the `Set` function, in fact you're just saying "if the value is Nothing, then set it as Nothing", which is redundant.

I believe the problem is that you're trying to assign that object Nothing reference to the textbox `.Text` property and that results in the exception.

`TextBox.Text` expects a `String` I don't see the reason of using `Nothing`. Create a `Function` to handle the `Nothing` values and show an empty string instead. Plus, it gives you the freedom of [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) your date as you like.

something like

```
Function getDateText(ByVal d As Date?) As String
  If d.HasValue = False Then
     Return ""
  End If

  Return d.Value.ToString("D")
End Function
```

and then call it when you want to set `txtAcknowledgeDate.Text`

```
txtAcknowledgeDate.Text = getDateText(thisEvent.AcknowledgeDate)
```